# Create a checkbox for tags in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox

Im editing a plugin because I want to create a checkbox for the tags the plugin has. In this moment Ive got in a variable, this array:

```
array(9) { [129]=> object(EM_Tag)#84 (15) { ["id"]=> string(3) "129" ["term_id"]=> string(3) "129" ["name"]=> string(35) "Accessible for non-English speakers" ["slug"]=> string(11) "non-english" ["term_group"]=> string(1) "0" ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> string(3) "129" ["taxonomy"]=> string(10) "event-tags" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["parent"]=> string(1) "0" ["count"]=> string(1) "0" ["fields"]=> array(0) { } ["required_fields"]=> array(0) { } ["feedback_message"]=> string(0) "" ["errors"]=> array(0) { } ["mime_types"]=> array(3) { [1]=> string(3) "gif" [2]=> string(3) "jpg" [3]=> string(3) "png" } } }
```

There are more tags but I just put one. I would like to generate a checkbox for each tag.

Comment: And what do you want your `checkbox` to look like?

Comment: I just want the Name and the id as a value to attached it to the new event created, because that is a form to create a new event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to iterate over the array that you provided and access the fields that way. I made a shortened array with proper indentation based on your example provided. It seems to be the same but let me know otherwise.

```
$array = array(
    129 => array(
        'id' => '129',
        'name' => 'Accessible for non-English Speakers'
    ),
    130 => array(
        'id' => '130',
        'name' => 'A second piece of information'
    ),
    131 => array(
        'id' => '131',
        'name' => 'A third piece of information'
    )
);

// Iterate over the array
foreach ($array as $c) {
    // Access the required data
    $id = $c['id'];
    $name = $c['name'];

    // Generate your checkbox
    print "<input type='checkbox' name='$name' id='$id'>";
}
```